# Get products that are in table 1 but not in table 2

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a table with 8 thousand products (table 1) and another table in which I have to manually add the products (table 2), I would like to know how many products I need to add, I have a key in the two tables to identify each product.

```
Table 1 - code_table1
A1001
A1002
A1003
A1004
A1005
A1006

Table 2 - code_table2
A1001
A1002
A1003
A1004
```

The problem is that in table 1 the column that has the key is called code_table1 and in table 2 the column that has the key is called code_table2

Expected result:

```
Products to add: 2
Keys to add:
A1005
A1006
```

You can help me with the consultation to obtain the mentioned thing, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table1 where code_table1 not in (
  select code_table2 from table2
);
```

Answer (score 0):

For Counting the no. of Products to add:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS products_to_add FROM TABLE_1 WHERE code_table1 NOT IN (
    SELECT code_table2 FROM TABLE_2
);
```

For finding the keys to add:

```
SELECT code_table1 AS keys_to_add FROM TABLE_1 WHERE code_table1 NOT IN (
    SELECT code_table2 FROM TABLE_2
);
```

And here's the sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e07fc58/6